# get points of intersection with the window’s boundary

Tags: cgal, voronoi, centroid

In official demo Triangulation_2，I want to show the centroid of every voronoi cell，but there are peripheral voronoi cells which are borderless . So it's easy to know that nobody can calculate the centroid of borderless face.
In oder to get centroid, are there some methods that can get the points of intersection with the window’s boundary?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYkz5.png)

Comment: You can probably use the sceneRect() method of the QGraphicsView : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop